# Active and Inactive div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to trigger functions when a certain div is no longer displayed. I have tons of divs which acts like Tabs but they aren't.
Any way to add a certain event listener on changing a div?
displaying and hiding divs using css.
I need something like :

```
div.active : //do stuff
div:inactive :  //do stuff
```

**Edit:**
need some event listener to listen to change of visible and invisible of the div

Comment: do you mean `:visible`?

Comment: in jquery it's $('div').is(':visible')

Comment: <div style="display:none">    //for hiding divs
<div style="display:block">   //for showing divs

Comment: @GoldenTabby I need something to be able to listen when the div is changing between the 2 modes (visible and not )

Comment: I suppose you could use MutationObserver.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to do this:

1. **JQuery:**  There are many tab samples created with JQuery. One of the best is [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/). You can view the source of the example to see how it's done.
2. **CSS:** Setting `display` to `none` to hide the element, and `block` to show it.

[Here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/50-nice-clean-css-tab-based-navigation-scripts/) is a collection of tabs implemented using different solutions.

Comment: Thanks, my next version will include this. i knew about this plugin , this is why i mentioned it in my question.

Comment: Your welcome, But Consider that it will not be a stable solution in addition to using large number of DIVs... Be lucky my friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('divid').style.display="none";  //Hide div
document.getElementById('divid').style.display="block";  //Show Div
```

In HTML:

```
<div style="display:none">
<div style="display:block">
```